# When does if become a statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As simple as it may sound, I'm trying to figure out what is a compound if statement. I know `if` is a keyword, and reading the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-suite) the syntax is:

```
if <expression>:
    <statement>
```

For example:

```
if True:
    print(1)
```

From my understanding, this is an if statement, but I want to break it down. When does it become the statement? What happens if I use a simple statement such as `pass` as a placeholder?

```
if True:
    pass
```

Because `pass` it's a statement too. Is the code above an if statement, a pass statement or an if clause?

The documentation it's also saying:

> A compound statement consists of one or more ‘clauses.’

From my understading a clause it's a keyword ending with a colon, like `elif` and `else`.

As such, if I don't have clauses inside `if True: pass`, is it still an if statement? If yes, why?

Comment: It's in the third paragraph at the top of the page: "A clause consists of a header and a ‘suite.’ The clause headers of a particular compound statement are all at the same indentation level. Each clause header begins with a uniquely identifying keyword and ends with a colon. A suite is a group of statements controlled by a clause. A suite can be one or more semicolon-separated simple statements on the same line as the header, following the header’s colon, or it can be one or more indented statements on subsequent lines. "

Comment: `if True: pass` is still considered an if statement, because it uses `if`, even if it doesn't do anything. Same as `pass` is considered a fully-valid expression even though it literally does nothing.

Comment: *"I know if is a keyword"* `if` is a keyword, but it can also be two different operators. (in a ternary if/else and in comprehensions)

Comment: What do you mean by *become* a statement?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy: `pass` is a statement, not an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` is a keyword. `if` alone is never a statement - nor an expression, for that matter. As stated in your question, an "`if` statement" is a statement of the following form:

```py
if <expression>:
    <statement>
```

It does not really make sense to say that it "becomes" a statement at some point in time; it simply *is* a statement. That is, the code above - all of it, not the `if` keyword by itself - is a statement. The `<statement>` part is also a statement, but this just shows that some statements (such as `if` statements) contain other statements.